# Append HTML doc to element using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've written this code using various online sources but I cannot seem to figure out the last part.

```
function loadajax (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){ 
        if(xhr.readyState  == 4){
            if(xhr.status  == 200) 
                document.ajax.dyn="Received:"  + xhr.responseText; 
            else
                document.ajax.dyn="Error code " + xhr.status;
        }
    }; 

    xhr.open('GET', this.href, true);
    var content = document.getElementsByTagName('article')[0];

    content.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}
```

It seems to work until I need to add content to my page. Indeed `content.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;` returns nothing. I am getting a simple HTML file, how can I post it in my page? what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason you're choosing to write the XHR from scratch, vice using jQuery or something else that wraps it nicely with a lot of other good functionality?

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery. Both for learning purposes and because I find it cleaner to use "pure" JS. By using jQuery I will never be able to write javascript from scratch without a library :).

Comment: Ok for learning.  For production, though, there's a lot to be gained for your project by re-using well-tested code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ajax calls are asynchronous. it will work if you'll move the `content.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;` line into the `onreadystatechange` function like this:

```
function loadajax (event) {
event.preventDefault();
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.onreadystatechange  = function() 
    { 
       if(xhr.readyState  == 4)
       {
        if(xhr.status  == 200) 
            document.ajax.dyn="Received:"  + xhr.responseText; 

            content.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        else
            document.ajax.dyn="Error code " + xhr.status;
        }
    }; 

xhr.open('GET', this.href, true);
var content = document.getElementsByTagName('article')[0];

}
```

Comment: Great response, I like that you included the explanation of *why* he needs to move the call to innerHTML.

Comment: thanks. it still doesn't seem to work but that might be something else :-/. btw, shouldn't xhr.open('GET', this.href, true); be in status=200 too then?

Comment: @SnippetSpace: are you missing the `xmlhttp.send();`?

Comment: Apparently :p. As I said, I'm new to this. It works now! thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Put your contet.innerHTML inside status 200 condition.

You are just assigning the value to content before it really exists. Before the ajax got it from server.